# share cookies between webview and chrome

Tags: android

Is this possible in android to share cookies between webview (WebChromeClient) and Chrome app

(analogue of how it is done in ios with [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/), where cookies shared between in-app SFSafariViewController and Safari app)

**Edit 0:** it looks like [google chrome custom tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) share cookies with chrome app, but it's separete chrome app activity, not view widget like webview

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware sadly no.
There are multiple reasons why browsers (and actually your app) would want and need this information private and protected (mostly security). 
I imagine if any cookies or private browser data were openly visible by any other app it would open the world of possibilities for abuse.

I may be wrong though, so anyone feel free to correct me.

Cheers

Comment: what about reverse, can webview cookie be set to chrome url

Comment: @Akashkumar I suppose no, for the same reason. Especially with strict GDPR policies today. Again I may be wrong though.

Comment: only default inbuild browser can be bit of altered while impossible for other like chrom etc